# How to get node package consumer directory from node_modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, packaging

I am trying to create a simple node module that creates a set of folders in the app that consumes it. I exported a simple `createLayout` function that creates the folders. I pushed my changes to git and did an `npm i` from another folder. Lets call the modules **`creator`** and **`consumer`** for the sake of explanation. When I try to call createLayout in consumer I am running in to several issues. I am in `E:\` drive.

Below is the index.js in creator:

```
import {sync} from 'mkdirp';

export function createLayout(config) {
  sync('./folder1');
}
```

And index.js in consumer:

```
var createLayout = require('creator').createLayout;
createLayout();
// with config createLayout({path: __dirname})
```

This results in creating a folder in E:\ not relative to consumer. So I tried including `__dirname`:

```
sync(__dirname + '/folder1');
```

Once again, this also creates a folder in E:\ not relative to consumer. I searched for bit like in various modules to see how they are doing when they are reading the config file, for instance webpack uses `process.cwd`. So I tried that too.

```
sync(process.cwd() + '/folder1');
```

Same, results in creating a folder in E:\ not relative to consumer. Then I tried to pass the __dirname or cwd through a `config` object.

```
// get __dirname from the `consumer` in config.path
sync(config.path + '/folder1');
```

But it ends up in following error:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'E:\'
```

I tried logging all the values in both creator and consumer:

```
console.log(__dirname, process.cwd(), config.path)
// creator: / / E:\projects\consumer
// consumer: E:\projects\consumer E:\projects\consumer E:\projects\consumer
```

I am using webpack with babel to pack the creator, plain js in consumer. I do not know what am I doing wrong. I am pretty new to nodejs ways of working.

**Update**

I am noticing that this is occurring only when I use webpack to build the creator. A simple `module.exports` works normally as anyone would expect. So I am including my webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'creator.js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    library: 'creator',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    fs: 'fs'
  }
};
```

Comment: Try this in creator: `sync('./folder1');`

Comment: @BobSponge That was my first tryout. The folder is created in E:\ not relative to `consumer`, If that had worked, then I wouldn't have had this issue at all.

Comment: I also fixed the mistake in the question, you see, stackoverflow doesn't allow small edits :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correct solution** is adding this line in [config](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target):

```
target: 'node'
```

this will make webpack to ignore modules like `fs` and `mkdirp` and some other.

Now no longer need to specify `externals`.

---

Incorrect solution given before:

Just add `mkdirp` to externals and it will resolve you problem:

```
  externals: {
    fs: 'fs',
    mkdirp: 'mkdirp'
  }
```

Comment: Man! that's all the issue was? May I ask you to elaborate on this?

Comment: Also what are all the situations where I have to put a module as external? before this I ran into `fs` not being defined and I had to put that as external too ...

Comment: Much better, thanks :) Also the first one was not a incorrect solution, but a specific one, while the second is more generic.